# Cannot Find Symbol in Main Class (Help, much confuse D: )

Tags: java

### So in my class I have to write a program that ask a user for a cat and dogs name and race and output the results. Its mostly finished until this last part.

```
package l3c3computerscience;
public class L3C3ComputerScience {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        Dog myDog = new Dog();

        myCat.createCat(); //error is here
        myDog.createDog(); //error is also here
    }

}
```

---

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package l3c3computerscience;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Mammal {
    public Scanner input;
    public Dog myDog;
    public Cat myCat;
    public void createCat()
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        myCat = new Cat();
        String name;
        System.out.println("What is this cat's name?");
        name = input.next();
        myCat.setName(name);
        String race;
        System.out.println("What is this cat's race?");
        race = input.next();
        myCat.setRace(race);
    }
        public void createDog()
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        myDog = new Dog();
        String name;
        System.out.println("What is this dog's name?");
        name = input.next();
        myDog.setName(name);
        String race;
        System.out.println("What is this dog's race?");
        race = input.next();
        myDog.setRace(race);
    }
        public void display()
        {
            System.out.println("I have a "+myCat.getRace()+" cat and its name is "+myCat.getName());
            System.out.println("I have a "+myDog.getRace()+" dog and its name is "+myDog.getName());
        }

}
```

---

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package l3c3computerscience;

/**
 *
 * @author Xander
 */
public class Cat 
{
    private String name;
    private String race;
    public Cat()
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.race = race;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setRace(String race)
    {
        this.race = race;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
        public String getRace()
    {
        return this.race;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("The cat's name is" + name);
        System.out.println("The cat's race is" + race);
    }
}
```

---

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package l3c3computerscience;

/**
 *
 */
public class Dog 
{
    private String name;
    private String race;
    public Dog()
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.race = race;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setRace(String race)
    {
        this.race = race;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
        public String getRace()
    {
        return race;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("The dog's name is" + name);
        System.out.println("The dog's race is" + race);
    }
}
```

---

It keeps giving me, cannot find Symbol under the first part. "createCat/Dog();" is underlined saying "cannot find Symbol"  Cant figure out why, :( Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say this but your current program design is off, way off:

- First of all, both Cat and Dog should extend from Mammal
- But having said that, Mammal needs to be re-written completely -- it should have no user-interface code, no Scanner, no println's, and instead it should have state (fields) and behaviors (methods) that Dog and Cat would share.
- Your Cat and Dog classes probably should have non-default constructors, should have constructors *with **parameters*** that allow setting of fields. Your current constructors with calls like `this.name = name;` set your fields to `null` values since these constructors have no parameters.

e.g.

```
public Dog(String name, String race) {
    this.name = name;
    this.race = race;
}
```

- The user interface code, the code that uses Scanner and has printlns in it should be elsewhere, likely you'll simply have this in your main method, wherever you place this such as the L3C3ComputerScience class.
- Perhaps then you would use static methods in the L3C3ComputerScience for createCat and createDog, but make sure that these methods are not `void` methods, but rather return a Cat or Dog object respectively.
- Consider giving these methods a Scanner parameter so that the main method can pass the Scanner into the method for it to use.

e.g.,

```
public static Dog createDog(Scanner input) {
    // code to interact with user and create a dog
    String name = // ..... use input to get name from user
    String race = // ..... use input to get race from user

    // use the new constructor you've created that takes parameters
    Dog dog = new Dog(name, race);     

    // return the Dog from the method to the caller
    return dog;  
}
```

and likewise for `createCat`

Answer (score -1):

As per your requirement:

First of all you need to create `Mammal` class object in `main` method, since `createCat()` and `createDog()` methods are in `Mammal` class.

Second, you are going to use `Mammal` class and that resides inside the
package named `l3c3computerscience`, so import `l3c3computerscience.Mammal`;

Finally your `L3C3ComputerScience.java` file looks like below:

```
import l3c3computerscience.Mammal;

public class L3C3ComputerScience {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mammal mammal = new Mammal();
        mammal.createCat();
        mammal.createDog();
        mammal.display();
    }
}
```

And run in sequence:

```
javac -d . Cat.java  
javac -d . Dog.java  
javac -d . Mammal.java  

javac L3C3ComputerScience.java  
java L3C3ComputerScience
```

Hope, it will fullfill your requirement.